# Or symbol not working

Tags: android

I want to make the user to fill all the particular edittext and cannot leave it empty. I use .isEmpty code and the or symbol "|". This is what I make:

```
if(!e_name.getText().toString().isEmpty()|!e_numb.getText().toString().isEmpty()|!e_pangkat.getText().toString().isEmpty()
    |!e_tarikh.getText().toString().isEmpty()|!e_masa.getText().toString().isEmpty())
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cannot empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }else {//another code}
```

when I run the code, even when the edit text is fill, it still toast "cannot empty" what did I do wrong?

Comment: `or` is `||`. `|` is bitwise or

Comment: you have to use || for above code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use double pipes for or `||`, single pipes are for bitwise operations

Also your if-statement is probably wrong, currently you check if the strings are **NOT empty** and give an error.
You should remove the `!` from the statements so you check if the strings **ARE** empty, then give the error.

```
if(e_name.getText().toString().isEmpty()||e_numb.getText().toString().isEmpty()||e_pangkat.getText().toString().isEmpty()||e_tarikh.getText().toString().isEmpty()||e_masa.getText().toString().isEmpty())
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cannot empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
}
else {//another code}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try like this**

```
 if(!e_name.getText().toString().isEmpty()||!e_numb.getText().toString().isEmpty()||!e_pangkat.getText().toString().isEmpty()
||!e_tarikh.getText().toString().isEmpty()||!e_masa.getText().toString().isEmpty())
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cannot empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
}else {//another code}
```

Comment: Please do not post code only answers, since the OP seems quite new it is better to explain your code rather than just bluntly say **try this**